# Does mmap allocate heap memory contiguously?

Tags: memory-management, mmap

Provided that:

- The size I request is a multiple of the page size
- The start address I request is the size + start address of the last allocation

If I always follow these rules when using mmap to allocate memory on the heap, will the addresses returned be contiguous? Or could there be gaps between them?

Comment: In which OS?  These things are OS dependent.

Comment: If it's not OS independent then I'm assuming the answer to my question is "no", as I want to write portable code.

Comment: "portable" is a very broad term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Answer:  Not necessarily.  There's a good chance it will "almost always work" in both limited an extensive testing on a variety of machines, but its definitely not good practice.  The MAP_FIXED flag is supported on most flavors of Linux but it is also buggy in my experience.  Avoid.

Better in your case is to simply allocate everything you need at once, and then assign pointers manually to each sub-section of the mapping:

```
int LengthOf_FirstThing = 0x18000;
int LengthOf_SecondThing = 0x10100;
int LengthOf_ThirdThing = 0x20000;

int _pagesize = getpagesize();
int _pagemask = _pagesize - 1;

size_t sizeOfEverything = LengthOf_FirstThing + LengthOf_SecondThing + LengthOf_ThirdThing;
sizeOfEverything = (sizeOfEverything + _pagemask) & ~(_pagemask);

int8_t* result = (int8_t*)mmap(nullptr, sizeOfEverything, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
int8_t* myFirstThing = result;
int8_t* mySecondThing = myFirstThing + LengthOf_FirstThing;
int8_t* myThirdThing = mySecondThing + LengthOf_SecondThing;
```

An advantage of this approach also being that each of things you're mapping don't have to be strictly aligned to the page size.  And most importantly, it assures fully contigious memory.

Longer answer:
Implementations of mmap() can freely disregard the 'hint' address entirely and so you should never expect the address to be honored.  This may be more common than expected, because some implementations may not actually support pagesize granularity for new mmap()'s.  They may limit valid starting maps to 16k or 64k boundaries to help reduce the overhead needed to manage very large virtual address spaces.  Such an implementation would always disregard an mmap() hint that isn't aligned to such boundary.

Additionally, mmap() does not allocate memory from the heap at all.  The heap is an area of memory created/reserved by the C runtime libraries (glibc on *nix) when a process is created.  malloc() and new/delete are typically the only functions that pull from the heap, along with any libraries that may use malloc/new internally.  The heap itself is typically created and managed by calls to mmap() internally.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the behavior you want with the MAP_FIXED flag. Unfortunately for your goal, it's not universally supported, so you'd want to check the return value to ensure that it gave you the allocation you requested. For good portability, you'd need a backup plan for when the call returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not specified but a so called "implementation detail". I.e. you should not rely on one behaviour or the other, but assume that the pointer is opaque and not be concerned with its exact value.

(That said, there can be a place and time for hacks. In that case you need to find out exactly how your OS behaves.)